# How to check whether the UISegmentedControl is selected or not by user?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uisegmentedcontrol

I got an app in which I allocate 5 `UISegmentedControl` dynamically into the view. And got a Done button at the end. My condition that to proceed into next step (when done button is pressed), all the `UISegmentControl`s "should be selected by user".

The default selection in segmentcontrol is none.
How to check whether all the `UISegmentedControls` in my view is selected by the user before action on the done button is executed?

Comment: Only one of the segment can be selected at a time, what do you mean by **all the uisegmentedcontrol in my view is being selected by the user**? Do you mean **all the uisegmentedcontrol in my view had been selected by the user**?

Comment: one choice can be selected .ok.but i have 5 uisegmentedcontrol in my view.how to check whether all are selected before one final donebutton press??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right from the apple document, this should answer your question:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger selectedSegmentIndex
```

Discussion
The default value is `UISegmentedControlNoSegment` (no segment selected) until the user touches a segment.

Hope you can use that to check whether the value is user selected or not, to prevent going to next page.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSLog(@"%i", self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex);
```

this results `-1` if no segment is selected.

Answer (score 0):

add target and action to your segmentControls for UIControlEventValueChanged.
From the selector you gave in action, check which segmentControl was changed, and set it's corresponding flag (ex: array of string which are @"0" for not selected and @"1" once selected).

At any time check which flags are not set, the corresponding segmentControls were never selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how u create an UISegmentedControl

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Title1", @"Title2", @"Title3", @"Title4",nil];
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 35);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pickOne:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];   
segmentedControl.tintColor=[UIColor grayColor];
```

Then to find which segment was selected,

```
NSString *category =[segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex: [segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]];

if(category==@"Title1"){
    //Do something here..
}
```

Hope this helps.... Happy Coding

Comment: The 2nd part of the code has to written inside the method called -(void)pickOne:(id)sender.... (this is according to the above code..)

Comment: thanks ..but how can i know all segmentcontrols are selected??

Comment: What do u mean by all segment controls are selected.... User will be able to select only one at a time....

Comment: sry ..how can i know that all the uisegmentedcontrols are selected??
i have more than one uisegmentedcontrol in my view??

Comment: u can identity each segment control separately by setting its tag property to unique values...

Comment: yeah thts the way ...thanks...hey can u write it as an answer??

Comment: @booleanBoy - no you cannot do that with UISegmentedControl. You can with NSSegmentedControl for cocoa projects not for iOS projects.